# Why Leetcode is not accepting the the solution of "Missing Number (Problem no:268)" problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this following code for the leetcode problem "Missing Number":

```
class Solution(object):
    def missingNumber(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        m=max(nums)
        for i in range(m):
            if i in nums:
                i+=1
            else:
                print(i)
                break
```

The problem is an array containing n distinct numbers in the range [0, n], return the only number in the range that is missing from the array.

It was asked to implement in O(1) extra space complexity and O(n) runtime complexity

This code is giving the right answer but leetcode is not accepting it. Could you please tell me what is the problem?

The program is in Python.

Comment: You're basically iterating through each element of the array, which is fine and technically O(n). However, you could optimize your function by using a binary search instead of an iterative approach. Such an algorithm would solve the problem in O(log(n)). Do you mind providing sample inputs so we can better understand what the problem expects?

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to print the output, rather than returning it?

Comment: Your main loop is O(n).  The operation `i in nums` is also O(n), making the overall O(n^2).

Comment: @jasonharper has an excellent point. Also, `if i in nums` isn't guaranteed to be an O(1) operation. If nums is a traditional array then that statement itself is O(n), making your algorithm O(n^2).

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your suggestion. It worked when I changed the command from 'print' to 'return'.  Sample input for this problem is [3,0,1] and output should be 2. I will try to make the solution O(n). Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Hint: If I give you a sequence of numbers from let's say 0 to 4, what would you expect them to sum to? Can you calculate that sum without actually adding all the individual elements? Now what would you get if you compared that expected sum to the actual sum of a similar list missing one element?